# Is there a way to enable scroller in Anycharts Qlik Sense extension, eg Bar Chart?

Tags: qliksense, anychart

Is there a way to enable scroller in Anycharts Qlik Sense extension, eg Bar Chart ?

For example, in Anycharts set using
// turn on X Scroller
chart.xScroller(true);

looking to do this in the Anycharts Qlik extension.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of the AnyChart extension (v3.5) does not support x- y-scrollers. We will take it into account for future updates and update the thread when it becomes available.